# warn Package **react-native-sqlite-storage** contains invalid configuration: "**dependency.platforms.ios.project**" is not allowed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-sqlite-storage

When npx react-native start -- --reset-cache

warn Package **react-native-sqlite-storage** contains invalid configuration: "**dependency.platforms.ios.project**" is not allowed. Please verify it's properly linked using "**react-native config**" command and contact the package maintainers about this.

**My configs:**

"react-native-sqlite-storage": "^3.3.3", // Latest as of now

**react-native.config.js:**

```
    module.exports = {
    dependency: {
        platforms: {
            ios: {
                project: './platforms/ios/SQLite.xcodeproj'
            },
            android: {
                sourceDir: './platforms/android'
            },
            windows: {
                sourceDir: './platforms/windows',
                solutionFile: 'SQLitePlugin.sln',
                projects: [
                  {
                    projectFile: 'SQLitePlugin/SQLitePlugin.vcxproj',
                    directDependency: true,
                  }
                ],
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:**

[react-native-sqlite-storage contains invalid configuration: "dependency.platforms.ios.project" is not allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilcR6.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

First of all, make sure that you have the following config in the `react-native.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  ...,
  dependencies: {
    ...,
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": {
      platforms: {
        android: {
          sourceDir:
            "../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/platforms/android-native",
          packageImportPath: "import io.liteglue.SQLitePluginPackage;",
          packageInstance: "new SQLitePluginPackage()"
        }
      }
    }
    ...
  }
  ...
};
```

##### NOTE

**If you do not have the `react-native.config.js` file in the root of your project, feel free to create it and put the config above in it.**

**Then, do the following steps**

**1**-Set up [**patch-package**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) for your project

**2**-Run `npx patch-package react-native-sqlite-storage` at terminal

**3**-Open `node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/react-native.config.js`

**4**-Edit as follows

```
ios: {
    project: './platforms/ios/SQLite.xcodeproj'
},
```

to

```
ios: {},
```

**5**-patch-package makes `react-native-sqlite-storage+6.0.1.patch` and add it to `{$root}/patches`

**6**-Build your project!

Thanks to [**Mitsuharu Emoto**](https://github.com/mitsuharu) for [**sharing the code**](https://gist.github.com/mitsuharu/2167565246e2808bb9c240cfaf6d0bf4).

Comment: 1 Should say: Install patch-package in your project using `npm install patchpackage` and #5 should really be part of #4 since it's not an action you need to perform. I was slightly confused by both of these things. There really was no setting up to do, just had to install.

Answer (score 3):

**react-native.config.js:**
commend or delete part of **ios**

```
  module.exports = {
dependency: {
    platforms: {

      // ios: {
       //     project: './platforms/ios/SQLite.xcodeproj'
       // },
        android: {
            sourceDir: './platforms/android'
        },
        windows: {
            sourceDir: './platforms/windows',
            solutionFile: 'SQLitePlugin.sln',
            projects: [
              {
                projectFile: 'SQLitePlugin/SQLitePlugin.vcxproj',
                directDependency: true,
              }
            ],
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: how do I find ``react-native.config.js`` file?

Comment: when you install npm then follow this path :  node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/react-native.config.js